# Send mail from C# application not really working?

Tags: c#, smtp, sendmail

I have an email application where a user can fill out a form and the info get's mail to the form admin. I have the correct server and email credentials being set and i do not get any errors when the mail is sent. The To and From addresses are the same (admin@thedomain.com) It is like the mail is somewhere in limbo. I know the email account works, because I send mail to it from outlook. Any thoughts?

update:
Regarding code, I have created an abstraction to the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient class. I can set another server and the code works. The server that does work is within my host’s network. The server that does not work is outside of the network. Strange thing is, like I said, I can setup the account in OutLook and I can send / receive mail fine. I’ll have to check with my vendor to see if the mail is indeed getting to their server.

Comment: Are you using SMTP ? Any code can be helpful.

Comment: Can you step through the code in debug and confirm there are no errors or negative responses from the SMTP server?  Can you check the SMTP server's logs to see if the mail came in?

Comment: Show us a code and tell if you're using MS Exchanage Server because i had some typical problems with it

Comment: PLease see my updates to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a DNS issue with my hosting company. I could send mail via outlook becuase I was direclty connecting to the mail servers. The MX records were screwed up. Thanks to all who looked

Answer (score 0):

My guess is permissions.  Can your app send an email to your address?

Comment: It jsut seems to be a ceratin mail host. Although, I can setup an Outlook account with the same credentials and server, and it goes out fine. Strange....

Comment: If its an external host; are you sure its not being picked up as spam?  Check out this link too; it might help you out:  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe .net's system.web.mail sends email via relay.  You need to check with your email admin to determine if your IP address is allowed on the server to relay mail.